# Modeling shapes like a pumpkin - How to get sharp creases using curves, screw modifier, and mesh-deform modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I'd looking for alternative approaches to modeling something with approximately radial symmetry like a pumpkin using a curve, a screw modifier, and mesh deform. The problem is how/if it possible to use the mesh deform to get sharp creases like on pumpkin or gourd.

[image]

Details:

1. Starting with the curve, the screw modified was applied for 360 degrees to form a solid.
   [image]
   [image]
2. A cylinder was added.
   [image]
3. The mesh deform was added to the curve and referenced to the cylinder, then bound.
   [image]
4. If the mesh is deformed the shape changes
   [image]
5. If a single vertex is moved, a deformation happens, but it is very smooth and broad.
   [image]

Is there a way to make the deformation sharper like in the pumpkin image above?

Note: It is understood that this geometry can be created using meshing in several ways. The question is specific to modeling using curves and modifiers available for curves.

Example file - [image]